# How to handle $numberDecimal property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

How can I handle $numberDecimal format in Angular side? I could see so many posts with mongo query solution.

Is there any way to handle this data type in front end side without accessing like below?

```
price.$numberDecimal
```

mongoose schema like below:

```
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128,
```

but when it returns the data on aggregate query getting $numberDecimal format like below,

```
price: {
    $numberDecimal: "105.09"
}
```

Expected output is:

```
price : 105.09
```

How can I handle $numberDecimal property in Angular side with minimal changes?
I need to display this value in Reactive forms also.

Comment: you can use decimal pipe for the same..

Comment: @HrishikeshKale can u pls post one example? I'm not that good angular.

Comment: my bad it will be better if you can handle this from the backend, trying to convert string to int and send it to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data={
        price: {
        $numberDecimal: "105.09"
      }
     }
data['price']=parseFloat(data.price.$numberDecimal);

console.log(data);   //{price:105.09}
```